# Suffix: must be X

Tags: suffixes

Is there a suffix (or any other construct) that I can use with a base to express that this must (or is meant to) happen? For example, instead of:

> This car must be recalled

use:

> This car is recall<suffix here>

The closest I've found is that in addition, the terms that are meant be added are called add*end*s. Can this be applied everywhere? Can the example's car be called "recallend"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn't any general suffix meaning "required to be..." in English that is productive (can be applied to any verb) to make adjectives or nouns.

The words you have come across like *addend*, *dividend* (in the meaning of: *thing to be divided*) come straight from Latin into English. Latin does, or did, have a general way of making "required to be..." adjectives from verbs, called the *gerundive*. You can see the same -end form in the famous quote: "Carthago del**end**a est" ("Carthage must be destroyed").

But in English you are stuck with using some kind of phrase (must/required/having to).

Comment: Right. We do have the _-able/-ible_ suffix for possibility modals, but nothing morphological dealing with modalities like deontic _should_ or _must_.

Comment: Gerundive of obligation or passive periphrastic?

Comment: _"You can see the same -end form in the famous quote: "Carthago delenda est"_. Welcome to EL&U, **Cato the Elder**! Er, I mean, Reign of Error

Answer (score 7):

Similar to John Lawler's  "able/-ible suffix for possibility modals" (in a comment to another answer), this comes close to the force of the modal *should*, but falls short of a requirement or *must*:

> The car is certainly **recall-worthy**.

> **-worthy**, *comb. form*
>
> Forming adjectives with the sense ‘****deserving** of what is
> specified by the first element**’, as BLAMEWORTHY *adj*., NOTEWORTHY
> *adj*., PRAISEWORTHY *adj*., etc.  (OED)

---

> One of the bitter ironies of the sustainability movement is that when
> society had apparently unlimited energy to build, we didn't have the
> wits to design for disassembly or reuse, and we were in the grip of
> the Modernist design fad, which produced more **demolition-worthy**
> monster structures than any other era. [K Sorvig and J. Thompson;
> *Sustainable Landscape Construction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sustainable_Landscape_Construction_Third/IDRKDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=demolition-worthy&pg=PA45&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> The suitcase was definitely **trashworthy**, covered with scuffs,
> dents, and dirt. But the zipper worked, which was all Grant cared
> about. [Rob Byrnes; *Holy Rollers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Holy_Rollers/4aYpCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=trashworthy&pg=PT163&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Those who evince these vices impair their relationships whether or not
> they perform any **resentment-worthy** actions. [Macalester Bell;
> *Hard Feelings: The Moral Psychology of Contempt*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hard_Feelings/aBdpAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22resentment-worthy%22%20acts&pg=PA273&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> The spotlight on the foreign workers problem faded rapidly. By
> 1993...several people told me that the topic was passé. ... At the same time, Japanese people became inured to them, and the mass media
> moved to newer and more **copyworthy** topics. [John Lie; *Multiethic
> Japan*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Multiethnic_Japan/3aGeH0keCGUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22copyworthy%22&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> If she still had a job, she could fill the next week's worth of papers
> with even more **headline-worthy** stories. [Joyce Lamb; *True
> Vision*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/True_Vision/lwKIDEbUahgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22headline-worthy%22%20stories&pg=PT39&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> To Augustine, hatred of people is simply a sin. Where it is targeted
> at people, it ultimately backfires: instead of being directed at
> something **hateworthy**, it is itself **hateworthy**. [T. Szanto and
> H. Landweer; *The Routledge Handbook of Phenomenology of Emotion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Routledge_Handbook_of_Phenomenology/vuzeDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hateworthy%22%20men&pg=PT761&printsec=frontcover)
> (2020)

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps resale worthy. But not recall worthy.

Comment: Hmm. There is a book [*Worthy of Recall*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Worthy_of_Recall/pH-_1dNR5q4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=recall-worthy&printsec=frontcover) Don't confuse this definition with "Forming adjectives with the sense ‘in a suitable condition for use in the environment specified by the first element’" (OED)

Comment: Yes, but that means something different. That means: the stuff in the book is worth remembering. One doesn't say that a product one buys such as a car is *worthy* of recall. recalled products and recalling people or situations are not the same.

Comment: *pivotable recall*? ("To depend or be centered") - if it's pivotable then we cannot proceed until it's done. *Your car's recall is pivotal to us continuing to provide your insurance. Non-compliance with manufacturer's recommendations will result in cancellation of coverage.*

Answer (score 4):

A common device in English to perform a similar role as the gerundive, is to deny the alternative possibility.

So for example, a film that should be viewed is "unmissable".

A car that needs repairs is "undriveable" - or at least, "unreliable", and quite possibly, "unroadworthy" (drawing on DjinTonic's answer about the -worthy suffix).

From the perspective of a manufacturer's staff talking, to say a car "must be recalled" would be strongly implied by saying they are "unroadworthy".

Answer (score 1):

*To-Be-Recalled*. That's what I would use and it sounds natural, though it's not a suffix.

Comment: This is my actual fallback choice

Answer (score 0):

You say a suffix 'or any other construct'. Well, it's not a suffix but you could (I wouldn't go as far as to say *should*!) say it's a 'must-recall'. We have 'must-have', after all.